# Get featured image URL from pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get image location of the featured image of a single post. My code below using `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` returns nothing. any idea what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
<?php
    $we_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_status' => draft, 'page_id' => $wp_page_id));
    while ( $we_query->have_posts() ) : $we_query->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo '<div class="buying-hero__image" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(&quot;'.wp_get_attachment_image_url($wp_page_id, 'full').'")></div>';

        }  
        echo '<div class="container">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';

    endwhile; wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Comment: Featured image of what? The individual posts? Then why are you passing a page id as first parameter …?

Comment: @CBroe yes an individual post of a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function named `wp_get_attachment_image_src` along with the function named `get_post_thumbnail_id`. This will return an array, in which you need the first element.

```
<?php
while ($we_query->have_posts()) :
    $we_query->the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($wp_page_id), 'full' );
        echo '<div class="buying-hero__image" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(\"' . $image[0] . '\")></div>';
    }  
    echo '<div class="container">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: $image[0] gives me this  `<div class="buying-hero__image" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(" http:="" localhost="" mywebite="" frontend="" www="" articles="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2017="" 06="" hybrid.jpeg")=""></div>`

Comment: I forgot to escape the double quotes (`"`) in `url()`. I updated my answer, it should work now ;)

Comment: im still getting this output `<div class="buying-hero__image" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(\" http:="" localhost="" mywebsite="" frontend="" www="" articles="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2017="" 06="" hybrid-car-buying-guide.jpeg\")=""></div>`

Comment: got it, used `\'` instead of `\"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

`the_post_thumbnail_url( $size );`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url